# App won't run after adding support design library

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm currently trying to implement the android design library on my app but after encountering a lots of problems after updating my SDK etc now I'm having trouble on actually using it. It gives me this error when running the app (gradle is already synced, clean and project rebuilt):

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I don't know why and how this happen but it only triggers when I add the snackbar line on my code:

```
Snackbar
                .make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), R.string.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.close, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Can anyone point out where and how this problem happens? I've also checked all my libraries and there are no duplicates on any. TIA

Comment: Please post the full error log.

Comment: Well that is the only error I have that is why I'm lost on why this happen.:(

Comment: This error always come when some libraries are conflicting. Please check your log-cat log and copy whole log. It will be more helpful to find the real cause.

Comment: Well the error appears on Gradle error message and not on the log-cat as it happens upon building the app and not while running. Also yes I am well aware about the conflicting libraries may cause this though I've also tried to create a new project importing all the same libraries I have on my current app yet the SnackBar works just fine which makes this more complicated. I'll try to post the whole gradle message tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I finally solved it. The gradle console doesn't provide me the real cause of the problem instead it just returns those lines I've provided on the question. What I did was to run gradle `dexDebug --stacktrace --info --debug` then the real problem appears which is:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Now this can be solved via:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

but this should not be the problem and when I checked on the External libraries I found out that the play-services 7.5.0 version did just cause me this problem:

[image]

So I downgraded the version into 6.5.87. Once again removed the multiDexEnabled on my build.gradle, sync and clean and now it works! :D